# Clicks at end of chirp signal

Tags: python, log-chirp

When creating a scipy chirp function I get some clicks at the start end the end.
The first one is quite easy to fix using a phase difference of 90 degrees.

The problem I have is that the end point is not `0`.

for an static signal I can use the following code:

```
period_samples = fs / f
periods = np.ceil(T * fs / period_samples)
T = periods * period_samples / fs
```

and then I have the next zero point where I can stop.

But how can I do something similar with a chirp

my code now is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import chirp

T = 1  # sec
fs = 44100  # samplerate
f0 = 20  # Hz
f1 = 20000  # Hz

t = np.arange(T * fs) / fs
Sig = chirp(t, f0, T, f1, 'logarithmic', 90)
```

Comment: Would be good to know what `chirp` does exactly. You can have a look at the source code at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/waveforms.py

Comment: @Olli I read the same text at [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.chirp.html)
Both of this texts does nothing say about how to shape the last point as close as possible to 0.

Comment: depending on what you're doing, you could just fade out the beginning and end with a smooth window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the code in Olli's comment](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/waveforms.py), the phase is going to be

```
beta = t1 / log(f1 / f0)
phase = 2 * pi * beta * f0 * (pow(f1 / f0, t / t1) - 1.0)
```

So to ensure you have a zero crossing at the end of your signal, you need to choose a combination of `t`'s end value and `t1` for which the phase is modulo $2\pi$.

From your code, the last value of `t` will be 44099/44100. So the `beta` value is:

```
beta = 1 / log(1000)
```

and the phase of the last sample in the signal will be

```
phase =  2 * pi * 1/log(1000) * 20 * (pow(1000, 44099/44100) - 1.0)
```

which will be close to modulo $2\pi$ if you have a ratio of `f1` to `f0` equal to 1000.007748 instead of 1000 (after a bit of playing in Excel).  Try setting `f1` to 20000.15495 instead of 20000.

**EDIT** : I made a mistake in the above and have corrected it. [Here's a Google Doc that has the spreadsheet I've used (read only) for the correction.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jKv0AbjV4sRBHHHzfMyGd-z1d2qy-E1J__B0-pj1li0/edit?usp=sharing)

Screenshot highlighting the close values below.

[image]

Comment: i was first trying what you did in excel. But i found out that excel have $log$ as $log10$ and python have $log$ as $ln$. to be sure... the $log$ is the $ln$? At this moment i can't figure out jet how calculate the $\frac{f_1}{f_0}$ back because it is in log and the powered value... Working on it

Comment: @Jan-Bert : I made a mistake in my original spreadsheet. See update and link to Google Doc which you can copy and play with.

Comment: I have tried out your calculation but compared to the answer of @Marcus Müller and Wikipedia the answers of your equation are different.  
the equations of you and Wikipedia looks similar but are slightly different: This is yours $\phi = 2 * \pi * f_0 * \frac{t_1}{\log_{10}(f_1/ f_0)} * (\frac{f_1}{f_0}^{t/t_1} - 1)$ compared to Wikipedia $\phi = 2 * \pi * f_0 * \frac{1}{\ln(f_1/ f_0)} * (\frac{f_1}{f_0}^{t_1} - 1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Olli Niemitalo pointed you [in the right direction](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30245/clicks-at-end-of-chirp-signal#comment56919_30245) already – it's all there in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.chirp.html):

> logarithmic, log, lo:
>
> $f(t) = f_0 \cdot \left(\frac{f_1}{f_0}\right)^{t/t_1}$
>
> $f_0$ and $f_1$ must be nonzero and have the same sign.

You know that frequency is the derivative of phase, i.e. phase is the integral of frequency, accounting for a constant offset that you might specify as `phi`.

So there's no ambiguity here:

$$\begin{align}
f(t) &= f_0 \cdot \left(\frac{f_1}{f_0}\right)^{t/t_1}\\
&\implies\\
\varphi(t) &= \int\limits_{t=t_0}^{t_1} f(t), & t\in\left[t_0,t_1\right]\\
&=f_0 \, \int\limits_{t=t_0}^{t_1} \left(\frac{f_1}{f_0}\right)^{t/t_1} dt +\phi_0&\| a= \frac{f_1}{f_0}>0\\
\varphi(t) - \phi_0&= f_0 \, \int\limits_{t=t_0}^{t_1} \left({e^{\ln a}}\right)^{t/t_1}\,dt\\
&= f_0 \, \int\limits_{t=t_0}^{t_1} {e^{\ln a\,\frac{t}{t_1}}}\,dt\\
&= f_0 \frac{1}{\ln a \frac{1}{t_1}}e^{\ln a\,\frac{t}{t_1}}\\
&=  \frac{f_0t_1}{\ln a}e^{\ln a\,\frac{t}{t_1}}\\
\end{align}$$
you want $\varphi(t_1)=0$, so setting:
$$\begin{align}
0 &= \varphi(t_1)-\phi_0\\
&\implies\\
\phi_0 &= \frac{f_0t_1}{\ln a}e^{\ln a\,\frac{t_1}{t_1}}\\
 &= \frac{f_0t_1}{\ln a}e^{\ln a}\\
 &= \frac{f_0t_1}{\ln a} a\\
 &= \frac{f_0t_1}{\ln f_1 - \ln f_0}\frac{f_1}{f_0}\\
 &= \frac{f_1t_1}{\ln f_1 - \ln f_0}\text.
\end{align}$$

There you go, derivation with nothing but basic math.

Now, for a matter of fact, things aren't quite so easy because of numerical accuracy when summing up phases in floating point numbers – but with the current scipy implementation, you should be pretty good for most cases.